# (R-Language) Running script individually works but not when running the script as a whole. Error in `-.POSIXt`(`*tmp*`)

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, statistics

this is my first post on Stack Overflow so bare with me if its too much. Im running this script on R-studios using the latest version of R.

Im having an issue where by I'm trying to run a script I've written and when doing so it immediatley stops and returns this error to me:

```
Error in `-.POSIXt`(`*tmp*`) : 
  unary '-' is not defined for "POSIXt" objects
```

However, when running the script "individually", i.e in this case, first running script for Q4 and then only after running the script for Q5 etc.. It works without any issues.

This is my script:

```
# Installing packages I will need

install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("tidyr")
install.packages("readxl")
install.packages("psych")
install.packages("car")

# loading packages

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readxl)
library(psych)
library(car)


# Importing the Data Frame 
aqdata <- read_xlsx("D:\\tVNS - Data Folder\\AnalitiQs\\Company_Y_base_data.xlsx")

# Inspecting the head, colnames and nrows to see that everything was imported successfully
head(aqdata)
colnames(aqdata)
nrow(aqdata)

# Using distinct to compare nrows to ensure that all rows are unique 
distinct(aqdata, Employee_ID)  

--------------
# Q4 Step 1: # Converting the stop Month column to a date vector 
aqdata$Stop_Month <- as.Date(aqdata$Stop_Month)

# Q4 Step 2 - Filtering employees by department & missing values (Q depends on if last working day is date of Stop_Month or (as I interpret) last day of work was 1 day before Stop_Month date)
workers_post28 <- aqdata %>% 
  filter(Department == "Operations" & is.na(Stop_Month))

# Q4 Step 3: Final Answer
num_rows4 <- nrow(workers_post28)
message <- paste("On the 28th of July 2020", num_rows4, "people worked within the Operations Department of company Y")
print(message)
--------------
  
# Q5 Step 1: Converting the Start Month column to a date vector 
  aqdata$Start_Month <- as.Date(aqdata$Start_Month)

# Q5 Step 2: Filtering employees by dep, permanent contract. &  28th of Dec 2019 
workers_on28Dec2019 <- aqdata %>%
  filter(Department == "Operations" & Type_of_Contract == "Permanent") %>%
  
# Q5 Step 3: Filtering resulting employees by condition start date before Dec 28th 2019 and Stop date after 28th of Dec 2019 (based on prev question interpretation)
  filter(Start_Month < as.Date("2019-12-28") & is.na(Stop_Month) | Stop_Month > as.Date("2019-12-28"))

# Q5 Step 4: Final Answer 
num_rows5 <- nrow(workers_on28Dec2019)
messageQ5 <- paste("On the 28th of Dec 2019", num_rows5, "people in the Operations department had a permanent contract")
print(messageQ5)

# Q5 Step 3.1: Because I was unsure if my result was correct, I decided to verify that no employee not satisfying my conditions were left in the dataframe. 

# Filter to only include employees who started working after December 28th, 2019
before_28dec2019 <- workers_on28Dec2019 %>%
  filter(Start_Month > as.Date("2019-12-28"))

# Count the number of rows in the final result
num_rowscheck <- nrow(final_result)

# Print the result
if (num_rowscheck == 0) {
  print("The resulting dataframe does not contain any employees who started working before December 28th, 2019")
}

--------------
  
# Q6 Step 1: Calculate sum of distance and dividing by length of column (Can also use mean() function for more concise code)
AverageDistance <- sum(aqdata$Distance_Work_KM) / length(aqdata$Distance_Work_KM)
  messageQ6 <- paste("The average distance to work for any employee who has ever worked for Company Y is ", AverageDistance, "KM")
  print(messageQ6)
--------------

# Q7 Step 1: Filter workers by gender with conditions satisfying working on 2020-07-28 --> Creating the groups 

Q7df <- aqdata %>%
    
# Step 1.1 Filter rows based on conditions of the question (using same interpretation from Q4 where NA in Stop_Month indicates that they were working on the 28th as this is their last working day)
    filter(Start_Month < as.Date("2020-07-28") & is.na(Stop_Month)) %>%
    
# Step 1.2 Group by gender
    group_by(Gender) %>%
    
# Step 1.3 Select Salary column to incl into subset DF 
    select(Gender,Salary)
    
# Q7 Step 2: Assumption checking first normality, then equality of variances 
describe(Q7df$Salary) # Getting M, SD and Kurtosis values for Normality assumption --> Skew/Kurtosis do not fall within -2 or +2 so its violated 
shapiro.test(Q7df$Salary) # Another way of testing the assumption --> Also indicates violation. 

# Both test indicate that the assumption is violated but our sample is 319 so it should be okay 

# Testing equality of variances 
leveneTest(Q7df$Salary ~ Q7df$Gender) # The test is non-significant meaning that the assumption is not violated 

# Q7 Step 3: Running the t-test 
Outcome <- t.test(Salary ~ Gender, data = Q7df) # Assuming equal variances b.c leven's was non-sig.

# Q7 Step 4: Final conclusions 
print(Outcome$estimate)
print(Outcome$statistic)
print(Outcome$p.value)
messageQ7 <- paste("The T-test indicates that there is significant differences between the means of Female/Male in terms of Salary")
print(messageQ7)

--------------
```

Notes: I know that there are a lot of comments here that should not be in a script but I've got them there for myself as Im answering questions to an assignment.

Question: Why am I getting this error.

As I've understood it, it is because Im trying to use an operator "-" on an object class. But Im not trying to do that, its just that the date format is year-month-day. Which R seems to recognize only when Im running the script individually, hence my confusion.

Any ideas on why this is happening only for when I run the entire script and how I can solve this issue?

Many thanks for anyone who takes their time helping me!

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who finds this and is struggling with a similar problem. For me, the issue was that I was using

---

to separate blocks of codes but I did not # comment it out and so the compiler, I guess started a new one with every ----.

When I commented them, the issue was solved!